# One row per product with all languages fields (from another table)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have three tables:

```
products (id) 
products_lang (name)
languages (code)
```

I want a row per product with all languages fields.

Example result:

```
id, name[es], name[en]
```

More info:

Table "products"

```
id_product | id_category
1 | 1
```

Table "products_lang"

```
id_product | id_lang | name
1 | 1 | Car
1 | 2 | Auto
```

Table "languages":

```
id_lang | code
1 | en
2 | es
```

Row result as I want:

```
id_product | id_category | name (in english) | name (in spanish)
1 | 1 | Car | Auto
```

It is possible only with MySQL?

Comment: Please share sample data in table form and expected outcome

Comment: i guess you are after of `PIVOT` \

Comment: You say two tables, but it looks like you've listed three. Can you please provide an example of the data in your tables. This looks like just a simple `JOIN`. Also, what flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How do these tables naturally join together? PK, FK etc

Comment: I want the row from product, and append to same row each field from products_lang (with id_product and id_lang) with field code in brackets from all languages.

Comment: I do it with PHP but i want if can i do with only sql

Comment: Wait, you want one row for each `product` with each `language` in a separate column?

Comment: I think he's looking for a cross join here but we need to see table schemas first

Comment: Can you provide some example data of what each table looks like?

Comment: Looks like a PIVOT. Again, which version of SQL?

Comment: What do your actual tables look like? What columns are in each table and how do the 3 tables relate to each other?

Comment: @HernánGabriel, your responses to Shawn are not helping us help you.  We need good sample data from each table that clearly shows the schema.  We also need a clear description of your expected result.

Comment: I edited my post, please read it now. Thanks

Comment: Much better thanks!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: OK see updated answer below - it works

Comment: After further comments, I've updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id_product, a.id_category, max(case when code='en' then [name] else null end) [name in english],
max(case when code='es' then [name] else null end) [name in spanish]
from products a join products_lang b on a.id_product=b.id_product
join languages c on b.id_lang=c.id_lang
group by a.id_product, a.id_category
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After further comments clarifying the issue, my original answer no longer applies. This is essentially a PIVOT operation. Since MySQL is a bit less graceful in its PIVOTs, I've used `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`. I also added in some orphaned and some missing data to demonstrate how the query will handle those.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ed63b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE products (id_product int, id_category int) ;
CREATE TABLE products_lang ( id_product int, id_lang int, name varchar(20)) ;
CREATE TABLE languages (id_lang int, code varchar(5)) ;

INSERT INTO products (id_product, id_category)
SELECT 1 AS id_product, 1 AS id_category UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2
;

INSERT INTO products_lang (id_product, id_lang, name)
SELECT 1 AS id_product, 1 AS id_lang, 'Car' AS name UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 2 , 'Auto' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 1 , 'Car' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 2 , 'Auto' UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 7 , 'voiture' UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 9 , 'autoa'
;

INSERT INTO languages (id_lang, code)
SELECT 1 AS id_lang, 'en' AS code UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'es' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'fr'
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s1.id_product
  , s1.id_category
  , s1.NameInEnglish
  , s1.NameInSpanish
  , s1.NameInFrench
FROM (
SELECT 
    p.id_product
  , p.id_category
  , MAX(IF(pl.id_lang=1, CONCAT(pl.name, '[', l.code, ']'),'')) AS NameInEnglish
  , MAX(IF(pl.id_lang=2, CONCAT(pl.name, '[', l.code, ']'),'')) AS NameInSpanish
  , MAX(IF(pl.id_lang=7, CONCAT(pl.name, '[', l.code, ']'),'')) AS NameInFrench
FROM products p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product
LEFT OUTER JOIN languages l ON pl.id_lang = l.id_lang
GROUP BY p.id_product
WITH ROLLUP
) AS s1
WHERE s1.id_product IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ed63b/1/0)**:

```
| id_product | id_category | NameInEnglish | NameInSpanish | NameInFrench |
|------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|--------------|
|          1 |           1 |       Car[en] |      Auto[es] |              |
|          2 |           1 |       Car[en] |      Auto[es] |              |
|          3 |           2 |               |               |  voiture[fr] |
```